# How to create where clause only by Expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, expression-trees

What I want to achieve is a simple where clause with expression tree (only):

```
Tags.Where(t => t.Title == "Exam")
```

what i have done so far :

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(EfTag), "t");
Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(EfTag).GetProperty("Title"));
Expression right = Expression.Constant("Exam");
Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(left, right);

var neededTags = myDataContext.Tags.where( e1 /* what should i do here WI?? */ );
```

Please do not refer me to [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) or [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx). i need to do this without using any Third part library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Now that you have the parameter and `==` operator call, you have to combine them together into a `Lambda`:

```
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<EfTag, bool>>(e1, pe);
```

You can later on use it in `Where` call:

```
var neededTags = myDataContext.Tags.Where(predicate);
```